# PHP echo command produces incomplete object definition resulting in JSON parsing errors in JQuery

Tags: php, json

I have a rather complex object which is constructed in php and sent to JQuery using JSON. 
The process works very well and efficient, but I am having no luck so far in solving this problem. For some reason I am not seeing what is happening here - still after 2 days, so could someone please point me in the right direction.

I have a number of functions that build the object. They all work fine and at the end of the process, the JSON is parsed successfully in JQuery. One of the functions which also happens to fetch data from a database and does some simple arithmetic, consistently results in JSON parsing errors. This function adds an array of stdClass sub-objects as properties to the main object. By not calling this function during the construct process, the JSON parse error goes away.

This is what I have found so far (I have isolated the problem area for simplicity purposes)

```
//The $dataObject is derived from a database with:
$dataObject = $db->loadObjectList();        // Using Joomla framework


001:    // The section of code in php which illustrates the problem

002:    $jsonOutput = json_encode($dataObject);
003:    dump($jsonOutput, '$jsonOutput');
004:    echo $jsonOutput;

005:    // Here are the results:

006:    // Dumping the array of stdClass objects to JDump produces the following:
007:    $jsonOutput =   {"resourceList":
008:    [
009:        {
010:            "assetCategory":"Accommodation",
011:            "assetCount":"1"
012:        },
013:        {
014:            "assetCategory":"Equipment",
015:            "assetCount":"3"
016:        }
017:    ]
018:    }

019:    // This is what is produced on screen with echo command.

020:    {"resourceList":[,]}    
// The individual sub-objects are not produced in the output.
```

I am at a loss as to why this is happening. I have tried different key names, sub-object definition names etc. to no avail.

In the overall model constructor, I have called other functions in the same location instead of this one and had no problems. I somehow it is limited to this function only.

Dumping the raw JSON into the JDump utility, produces the expected results, but using echo to produce the results on screen in the browser, produces an ill-formed array of "nothing" which results in JSON parsing errors in JQuery down the line.

Does anyone have any idea on this?

Thanks in advance

some more examples of the problem:

The full object as produced with json_encode an then echo:

```
{"568":{"logId":"568","firstName":"Jonathan","lastName":"Harper","fullName":"Jonathan Harper","email":"jih13@hotmail.com","telephone":"07817167228","countryId":"234","country":"United Kingdom","address":"","subject":"Hi","message":"Hello.\n\nHope you're all well there. I actually came to The Casa in June last year and I've got some free time in October to come over for the surf 'n' stay for about 5 days.\n\nI just wanted to confirm the cost for that time.\n\nThanks for your help.\n\nJonathan.","partySize":"1","itemToken":"-","parentToken":null,"packageGroupId":"2","packageGroup":"Surf n Stay","packageNameId":"5","packageName":"7 nights - Private Single Room - 5 days Surf course","fromDate":"2013-10-19","toDate":"2013-11-02","nights":"14","ipAddress":"-","terms":"0","createdDate":"2013-09-17","logStatusId":"1","logStatus":"Pending","statusOrder":"1","displayParams":"background-color:#FF8080;font-weight:700;","groupList":[{"enqLogDetId":"700","order":"0","enqLogId":"568","firstName":"Jonathan","lastName":"Harper","gender":"Male","fitnessLevel":"","dateOfBirth":"0000-00-00","ageGroupId":"1","ageGroup":"Unknown","address":"","countryId":"234","country":"United Kingdom","email":"jih13@hotmail.com","promote":"0","notes":null,"statusId":"2","status":"Current","age":null,"fullName":"Jonathan Harper"}],"responseList":[{"responseId":"460","responseEnqLogId":"568","responseAdminUserId":"1","response":"Hello.\n\nHope you're all well there. I actually came to The Casa in June last year and I've got some free time in October to come over for the surf 'n stay for about 5 days.\n\nI just wanted to confirm the cost for that time.\n\nThanks for your help.\n\nJonathan.","responseToken":"-","responseDate":"2013-11-14","responseMode":"Details Modified","responsePackageGroupId":"2","responsePackageNameId":"5","responseFromDate":"2013-10-19","responseToDate":"2013-11-02","responsePartySize":"1","responseNotes":"Enter note here","responseStatusId":"2","responsePackageGroup":"Surf n Stay","responsePackageName":"7 nights - Private Single Room - 5 days Surf course","responseStatus":"Current","responseUserId":"42","responseLogStatus":"Pending","responseLogStatusId":"1","responseUserName":"Joe Stokes","seasonPrices":[{"seasonName":"2013 Mid Season","seasonCode":"13-Mid","seasonStart":"2013-10-01","seasonEnd":"2013-10-31","book_in":"2013-10-19","book_out":"2013-11-02","seasonPrice":"410.00","seasonNightPeriod":"7","billingCriterium":"Per room per period","inventoryId":"6","unitCapacity":"1.0000","bedCount":"1.0000","unitUseage":"Private","bookingDays":14,"seasonDays":12,"seasonSplitPrice":702.86},{"seasonName":"2013 Low Season","seasonCode":"13-Low","seasonStart":"2013-11-01","seasonEnd":"2013-11-30","book_in":"2013-10-19","book_out":"2013-11-02","seasonPrice":"340.00","seasonNightPeriod":"7","billingCriterium":"Per room per period","inventoryId":"6","unitCapacity":"1.0000","bedCount":"1.0000","unitUseage":"Private","bookingDays":14,"seasonDays":2,"seasonSplitPrice":97.14}],"resourceList":[,]}]}}
```

You can clearly see the malformed objects at the end.

The output of     `echo '<pre>'.print_r($dataObject, true).'</pre>';` produces the following:

```
            Array
        (
            [568] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [logId] => 568
                    [firstName] => Jonathan
                    [lastName] => Harper
                    [fullName] => Jonathan Harper
                    [email] => jih13@hotmail.com
                    [telephone] => 07817167228
                    [countryId] => 234
                    [country] => United Kingdom
                    [address] => 
                    [subject] => Hi
                    [message] => Hello.
                    [partySize] => 1
                    [itemToken] => -
                    [parentToken] => 
                    [packageGroupId] => 2
                    [packageGroup] => Surf n Stay
                    [packageNameId] => 5
                    [packageName] => 7 nights - Private Single Room - 5 days Surf course
                    [fromDate] => 2013-10-19
                    [toDate] => 2013-11-02
                    [nights] => 14
                    [ipAddress] => -
                    [terms] => 0
                    [createdDate] => 2013-09-17
                    [logStatusId] => 1
                    [logStatus] => Pending
                    [statusOrder] => 1
                    [displayParams] => background-color:#FF8080;font-weight:700;
                    [groupList] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [enqLogDetId] => 700
                                    [order] => 0
                                    [enqLogId] => 568
                                    [firstName] => Jonathan
                                    [lastName] => Harper
                                    [gender] => Male
                                    [fitnessLevel] => 
                                    [dateOfBirth] => 0000-00-00
                                    [ageGroupId] => 1
                                    [ageGroup] => Unknown
                                    [address] => 
                                    [countryId] => 234
                                    [country] => United Kingdom
                                    [email] => jih13@hotmail.com
                                    [promote] => 0
                                    [notes] => 
                                    [statusId] => 2
                                    [status] => Current
                                    [age] => 
                                    [fullName] => Jonathan Harper
                                )
                        )
                    [responseList] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [responseId] => 460
                                    [responseEnqLogId] => 568
                                    [responseAdminUserId] => 1
                                    [response] => Hello.
                                    [responseToken] => -
                                    [responseDate] => 2013-11-14
                                    [responseMode] => Details Modified
                                    [responsePackageGroupId] => 2
                                    [responsePackageNameId] => 5
                                    [responseFromDate] => 2013-10-19
                                    [responseToDate] => 2013-11-02
                                    [responsePartySize] => 1
                                    [responseNotes] => Enter note here
                                    [responseStatusId] => 2
                                    [responsePackageGroup] => Surf n Stay
                                    [responsePackageName] => 7 nights - Private Single Room - 5 days Surf course
                                    [responseStatus] => Current
                                    [responseUserId] => 42
                                    [responseLogStatus] => Pending
                                    [responseLogStatusId] => 1
                                    [responseUserName] => Joe Stokes
                                    [seasonPrices] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [seasonName] => 2013 Mid Season
                                                    [seasonCode] => 13-Mid
                                                    [seasonStart] => 2013-10-01
                                                    [seasonEnd] => 2013-10-31
                                                    [book_in] => 2013-10-19
                                                    [book_out] => 2013-11-02
                                                    [seasonPrice] => 410.00
                                                    [seasonNightPeriod] => 7
                                                    [billingCriterium] => Per room per period
                                                    [inventoryId] => 6
                                                    [unitCapacity] => 1.0000
                                                    [bedCount] => 1.0000
                                                    [unitUseage] => Private
                                                    [bookingDays] => 14
                                                    [seasonDays] => 12
                                                    [seasonSplitPrice] => 702.86
                                                )

                                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [seasonName] => 2013 Low Season
                                                    [seasonCode] => 13-Low
                                                    [seasonStart] => 2013-11-01
                                                    [seasonEnd] => 2013-11-30
                                                    [book_in] => 2013-10-19
                                                    [book_out] => 2013-11-02
                                                    [seasonPrice] => 340.00
                                                    [seasonNightPeriod] => 7
                                                    [billingCriterium] => Per room per period
                                                    [inventoryId] => 6
                                                    [unitCapacity] => 1.0000
                                                    [bedCount] => 1.0000
                                                    [unitUseage] => Private
                                                    [bookingDays] => 14
                                                    [seasonDays] => 2
                                                    [seasonSplitPrice] => 97.14
                                                )
                                        )
                                    [resourceList] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [category] => Accommodation
                                                    [available] => 1
                                                )

                                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [category] => Equipment
                                                    [available] => 3
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
```

Comment: If you cast it as an array then does it break things? `002:    $jsonOutput = json_encode((array)$dataObject);`

Comment: Are any of the objects in `$dataObject` a resource?

Comment: If you change line `001` to `echo '<pre>'.print_r($dataObject, true).'</pre>';` then do you get expected results in the browser?

Comment: Casting it as an array or object makes no difference.

Comment: Using the '<pre>' ... option, produces the expected output - a well-formed object - the same result I get using JDump. Echo still presents the same problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "are any of the objects in .. a resource" - I'm fairly new to OOP. Perhaps the structure of the array in the above example could answer that for you. Btw, for simplicity, I've limited the output to represent only one record in the total data-set.

Comment: Problem solved: The problem originated in the Joomla component and relates to that only. Somehow, under "special circumstances" the JSON string gets stripped before the html is rendered to the browser. Easy fix from component developer implemented.